# Handling in View vs Handling in Controller Extjs

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller

When we working on a extjs MVC project, we can handle a view event either inside the view or controller. How do we decide what events been handled in the view and what events been handled in the controller. What is the best practice.

For example, I need to pop up a window when a button is clicked. Should the creation of the window goes to controller or resides in the container view object.

Comment: Have you checked out the ExtJS MVC example? I would recommend going through it if you haven't. It provides a simple but helpful example http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.I did,my problem is when there is a lot of similar button handlers resides in my view, would it be better to move them all to controller. As usually we put those handlers inside the view, if I am not wrong.

Comment: For example, I need to pop up a window when a button is clicked. Should the creation of the window goes to controller or resides in the container view object.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is utilize the control() method within your controller definition. For example, take this code,

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

init: function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport > panel': {
            render: this.onPanelRendered
        },
        '#editform button[action=save]': {
            click: this.onClick
        }
    });
}
});
```

This is from the MVC example. You'll notice that it is using the ComponentQuery Language (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) to select a set of Ext objects to assign the `render()` event. This is saying, for all panels in the viewport, call `onPanelRendered()` for the `render()` event. So in your case, you want to select some buttons. So I added another example that selects some form with an id of `editform` and then select the button that contains the property `action = save`. You can get very specific with these component queries. I would suggest reading ComponentQuery portion of the API to see further examples. This depends on how you are attempting to select the buttons.

Comment: Moreover, so you are suggesting put all the button handling into the controller instead of put them inside the view class

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to MVC maybe you should only listen to events in the controller, once you have developed a couple of projects and you've gained discipline and enjoyed the benefits of listening events in a controller then you would be able to mix it up (when to use a handler and when to use a controller is gonna become obvious).

E.g If you have a FormPanel and you are only gonna listen to a button's click perhaps it doesn't make much sense to create a controller just for that, but in the other hand if you have a grid with a toolbar, action buttons, itemClick's etc then it would be a good idea to have a controller for that view.

**The fact that you are using MVC does not mean you are not allowed to use handlers anymore, but do it wisely.**

Best regards.

Comment: Hi code4jhon, thank you very much,it's indeed the first extjs mvc project, thank you for the answer